# how to call thingspeak api in jquery ajax using a button on your plugin?

Tags: jquery, matlab, api, channel

Hi Team i cant able to send request to my channel i created, i have the following code on Jquery ajax. nothing happens on my channels on client side.;

What exactly am i missing from this logic, please help me my button does not seem to do any call request to my channel.

```
<script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"> 
  $(document).ready(function){
    $.ajax({
      url:'https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/YYY/fields/field8/last.txt?api_key=XXX',
      type:'GET',
      data:{
        format:'text'
      },
      success:function(response){
        alert(response);
      },
      error:function() {
        $('#error').text("There was an error processing your request.Please try again");
        $('#singlebutton').append(data);
      }
    });

  });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have code inside a `<script>` tag that already have a `src`

So your:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"> 
   $(document).ready(function){...
</script>
```

should be:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
   $(document).ready(function){...
</script>
```

Comment: I am doing the second step, but i am now getting unexpected token ')

Comment: @TgcobzaMkontwana You have `function){` it should be `function(){`

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ')' when i am inspecting it on the browser on chromse, its coming from my $(document).ready(function){ }

Comment: Thanks it seem its doing something, now challenge i am getting my channel is not updating for seeing the last field i want to get on my channel dashboard. The alert is poping -1 message on the browser as equivalent to POSTMAN response when using GET method.

Comment: The URL you are using is not formatted correctly.

Try: https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/YYY/fields/8/last.txt?api_key=READAPIKEY

Replace with your channel number and read key.

Comment: @iohans There is nothinjg wrong with the url in the search.

Answer (score 0):

Th URL you are using is not formatted correctly.

Try: https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/YYY/fields/8/last.txt?api_key=READAPIKEY

Replace with your channel number and read key.